# find which line has the most vowels from a file

Tags: c, arrays, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

create function   int isVowel( char c )
 create function   int vowels( char s[] )

Which string from the file contains the most vowels
   - in the case of the tie, show just the 1st
   @ obviously should use the functions
above is what i am trying to do but i am not entirely sure on how to actually do it i could use some hints

I'm just not entirely sure how to do this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int isvowel(char c)
{
    int vowel=0;
    int i;
    int x=0;
    //for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    //  counter[i]=0;}
    for(i=0; i <c; i++)
    {
        if (c=='a' || c=='A')
            vowel++;
        else if (c=='e' || c=='E')
            vowel++;
        else if (c=='i' || c=='I')
            vowel++;
        else if (c=='o' || c=='O')
            vowel++;
        else if (c=='u' || c=='U')
            vowel++;
    }

    return vowel;
}
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char max[1024];
    char** buff;
    int i=0 ,num = 5;
    FILE *infile;
    int lc = 0;     //counts how many lines there are
    int p;

    //asks for file name if none is supplied
    if ( argc < 2 )
    {
        printf("Must supply file name\n");
        return 1;
    }
    infile = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    //checks to see if file opens
    if ( infile == NULL )
    {
        printf("could not open  %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    buff = (char**)calloc(sizeof(max),sizeof(char));
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<num;k++){
        buff[k] = (char*)calloc(sizeof(max),sizeof(char));
    }
    while(fgets(max,sizeof(max),infile)){
        strcpy(buff[i],max);
        i++;
    }
    int x;
    for(x =1; x<i;x++){
        lc++;
        printf("%d:%s",x,buff[x]);
    }
    p = isvowel(i);
    printf("your number of vowels is:%d",p);

    return 0;
}
```

should print a string with most vowels 
right now I can't even get it to count any vowels

Comment: `char c` and `for(i=0; i <c; i++)` and `if (c == 'a' || c == 'A')` ??? That doesn't make much sense. What is the loop for?

Comment: And in the `main` function: `p = isvowel(i);`? That doesn't make sense either, together with lots of other stuff. Please try to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code.

Comment: the loop is to go through each character of my file and check for a vowel

Comment: But it *doesn't*, it just loops from `0` to `c - 1` (inclusive) and check the value of `c` (which doesn't change) over and over again.

Comment: @cdude In the loop you are checking the same character over and over since c doesn't change in the loop.

Comment: and like i said i am not entirely sure what i am doing sorry

Comment: i tried sending a whole string in and making char c an array but it didn't work

Comment: @cdude - You have a lot of issues in your code (which is OK as a beginner - we've all been there).  I'd suggest first clean up your warnings then make sure the parameters you are passing in to a function match what the function is expecting.  Right now you are passing an integer to isvowel() but the function is expecting a character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A character is either vowel or not:

```
int isVowel(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, let's implement your other function:

```
int vowels(char s[]) {
    int size = strlen(s);
    int output = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) output += isVowel(s[i]);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: You know that the `vowels` function won't work very well, as `sizeof(s)` is the size of a *pointer*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's been a long while since I have written my last C program. It is quite possible that I do not remember well how the size of an array should be calculated, nevertheless, before I have written this answer I have found several sources suggesting that this is how one should calculate the size of an array in C.

Comment: Yes, but when you pass an array to a function it decays to a pointer to its first element. As an argument declaration, `char s[]` is translated as `char *s`. Once the decay to a pointer has happened, all information about the array is lost, including its size, and all you're left with is a pointer to a single element.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understand your point and find it a good one. However, as the asker described, vowels will only get an array as a parameter, so calculating its size and passing it is not really an option. So, we need to detect when we have ended to the end of the loop, without being able to determine its size with the formula in the function. I wonder what that end sign might be. I believe that for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {/*...*/} would be an alternative, but if we cannot be sure about this, then I think we will need to store the end sign as the last element of the array.

Comment: And a loop like that is how you iterate over null-terminated byte string (and if the input is read with `fgets` then it will be properly terminated). Or use `strlen` to get the length.

Comment: i actually ended up using ```strlen(s)``` and thanks for the help it is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

how about try this one, first, initialize the p to 0

```
int p = 0; // would be accumulated in another loop
```

and, revised the x loop,

```
for(x =0; x<i;x++){ // start with 0 for checking from buff[0]
    lc++;
    printf("%d:%s",x,buff[x]);
    for(int y=0; y<sizeof(max); y++){ // add another loop
        p += isvowel(buff[x][y])); // revise and move here
    }
}
```

it would be helpful to research the "switch case" and "tolower"

Comment: @cdude another loop was added to set a char

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this function:

```
int vowel(char *s, size_t len)
{
    int vowelCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        switch (s[i])
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
            case 'i':
            case 'I':
            case 'o':
            case 'O':
            case 'u':
            case 'U':
            {
                ++vowelCount;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return vowelCount;
}
```

Ask away if something's unclear.